# How to resolve "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'" in notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, xlwings

I installed a package in my notebook by running in a cell the following command:

```
!pip install packagename
```

but when I try to import the package, I'm getting the following error:

```
import packagename as pn
--> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packagename'
```

I don't change my kernel between these commands, and also it seems installed correctly since running the install command again detects the installed package. I also tried re-installing it without success. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

To install any package on windows

```
pip install packagename
```

MacOS

```
python3 -m pip install packagename
```

Linux

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```